# Conditional apostrophe at start and end of dict.get() result

Tags: python

I'm using an f-string to write an SQL query; this is the part of the query I need help with:

```
f"'{contact.get('Title', 'Null')}', '{contact.get('Location', 'Null')}', '{contact.get('Industry', 'Null')}'"
```

Each of the 3 `dict.get()` functions above is wrapped in apostrophes so that the SQL query will regard them as string.

The problem is that if the dict key doesn't exist (and returns `'null'`), the string will still be wrapped in apostrophes. This means that SQL query will recognize it as a string called "Null" (rather than an NULL value).

Is there a short and efficient way to make the apostrophe at the start and end of the string conditional, so that it appears only if a value was found using the `dict.get()` command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a wrapper. You can even take the opportunity to make the call shorter by setting a default parameter

```
def cget(x, default='Null'):
    out = contact.get(x, default)
    return out if out == default else f"'{out}'"

f"{cget('Title')}, {cget('Location')}, {cget('Industry')}"
```

Answer (score 0):

**I realized while writing the question that you can just do this:**

```
f"'{contact.get('Title', 'Null')}', '{contact.get('Location', 'Null')}', '{contact.get('Industry', 'Null')}'".replace("'Null'", "Null")
```

Any other interesting solutions are more than welcome...